# Syntax error near CASE on postgres function

Tags: postgresql, hasura

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.defaultmapviewport(hasura_session json)
 RETURNS viewport_info
 STABLE
AS $function$
    case hasura_session ->> 'x-hasura-default-country-code'
        when 'FR' then select lat, lng from places where slug_en = 'city-paris' 
        when 'ES' then select lat, lng from places where slug_en = 'municipality-madrid'
    end;
END $function$ language SQL;
```

I'm getting a syntax error near case, even though it seems right. What could be the problem?

Viewport info:

```
create table viewport_info(
    lat float,
    lng float
);
```

Comment: `CASE` cannot exist on its own, it needs to be part of larger query e.eg. `SELECT CASE ...`. In other words you inverted the statement. See [CASE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @AdrianKlaver commented, a `CASE` expression can't stand on its own, it must be part of a `SELECT` query. You'll want to use

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.defaultmapviewport(hasura_session json)
RETURNS viewport_info
STABLE
AS $function$
  SELECT lat, lng
  FROM places
  WHERE slug_en = (CASE hasura_session ->> 'x-hasura-default-country-code'
    WHEN 'FR' THEN 'city-paris' 
    WHEN 'ES' THEN 'municipality-madrid'
  END);
$function$ language SQL;
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1879c62a016a59ea3ce9d2a84a234d87))</sup>

Comment: i'm getting a return type mismatch in function declared to return viewport_info, I'll update question with the viewport_info create statement

Comment: @PlayMa256 Ah, there was a stray `END` at the end that I copied from the question. Fixed!